# URL / form_open issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

I am new to Codeigniter. I have been having a issue with a form I am working on for signup/register. It appears that ether I am using `form_open(CONTROLLER/METHOD);` wrong of I have configured something wrong.

Here is the form I am working with:

```
<?php
    echo form_open("main/login_validation"); 

    echo validation_errors();   

    echo "<p> Email:";
    echo form_input('email');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p> Password:";
    echo form_password('password');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Login');
    echo "</p>";



    echo  form_close();
    ?>
```

Snippet from main controller:

```
      public function login_validation () {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');    

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){

                redirect('main/view_members');              
            }
        else {
            $this->load->view('login');             
            }
    }
```

the `echo form_open('main/login_validation');` Looks right to me but idk.
When I test it this is what I get:

```
http://localhost/main/localhost/main/login_validation
```

I have replaced the actual URL with localhost as I dont want to post my site here.
I am using mod_rewrite / Apache2 server. Anything I can add to help please let me know.

Comment: have you tried /main/login_validation - and do you have a route set up for this method?

Comment: @KaiQing: Yes, same result still getting my baseurl after the main/

Comment: have you set your `base_url` on `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: It was, I have been trying it with out it set.

Answer (score 0):

echo form_open('controller/function');

You must use single quotes for codeigniter syntax

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could have three possible things wrong here:

1. You may have an invalid domain name / host name in your config.php (I typically leave this blank or set it to the exact base domain name)

   `$config['base_url']     = '';  // leave blank to be safe or set to known hostname`
2. Or you are not calling your `/controller/method` correctly. You need to make sure for your above code that what you are calling is in the folder `/application/controllers/` and controller is name `Main` (file: main.php).

   Inside that `Main` controller, you should have a function called `login_validation()` otherwise this will fail.
3. Or finally, it is an issue with calling `form_open("main/login_validation");` vs `form_open("/main/login_validation");`

   *(notice the first **/** ?)*

Comment: I erased my base url - good there
Also edited the question to include my controller / function.
and tryed /first didnt change.